# 'Undefined' returned while retrieving mongoose document elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap, mongoose

I am trying to display my mongodb data in a bootstrap template.

api.js

```
var Software = require('../models/dbSoftware.js');
exports.show = (function(req, res) {
Software.find({Publisher: req.params.format}, function(error, softwares) {
    res.render('searchpage', { searchText: req.params.format, softwares: softwares}); 
})
});
```

Software Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var softwareSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    SoftwareName: String
    , Size: String
    , Publisher: String
    , Product: String
    , Version: String
    , Language: String
    , License_Type: String
    , Description: String
    , License_Key: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Software', softwareSchema);
```

searchpage.ejs

```
<td><%= softwares.Product %></td>
```

This returns undefined value. Any softwares.* returns 'undefined'.

When I edit searchpage.ejs to:

```
<td><%= softwares%></td>
```

The output is:

```
{ License_Key: 'computing', Description: 'Licensed', License_Type: 'English', Language: 'UNKNOWN', Product: 'Test Test', Publisher: 'Test', Size: '231.6MB', SoftwareName: 'Test.zip', _id: 5252c407d9b28d1e4c000001, __v: 0 }
```

//which is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), `softwares` will be an `Array` for all successful (`error == null`) queries, regardless of the number of documents found:

```
<%= softwares.length %>
<%= softwares[0].Product %>
```

If you only want a single document, you'll want to use [`.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead:

```
Software.findOne({Publisher: req.params.format}, function(error, softwares) {
    // ...
});
```

```
<% if (softwares != null) { %>
    <%= softwares.Product %>
<% } %>
```

Or, you can [iterate over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `softwares`:

```
<% softwares.forEach(function (software) { %>
    <%= software.Product %>
<% }) %>
```